# JS - Detect when a user clears a field

Tags: javascript, jquery, calculator

I'm creating a calculator for my current web project, it works very well but as I was playing with it, it came to my attention that clearing the third field caused the script to output NaN.

I'm fairly new to Javascript, and I attempted to do

```
 if($('#field11').val() == '' || $('#field12').val() == '' || $('#field13').val() == ''){
     $('#result1').text('')
 }
```

But that doesn't to fix the issue. I've looked for a solution to this problem, but it's as if no one on the internet has had a problem like this! I need to be able to clear the output (#result1) if any one of the inputs are cleared.

This is my full code:

```
 $(document).ready(function(){

     $('#field11').keyup(function(){
         if($('#field12').val() != '' && $('#field13').val() != ''){
        $('#result1').text(commafy(Math.round( $('#field11').val() + $('#field12').val() / $('#field13').val() * 1.5)) + ",99");
        }
     });
        $('#field12').keyup(function(){
        if($('#field11').val() != '' && $('#field13').val() != ''){
        $('#result1').text(commafy(Math.round( $('#field11').val() + $('#field12').val() / $('#field13').val() * 1.5)) + ",99");
        }
     }); 
     $('#field13').keyup(function(){
         if($('#field11').val() != '' && $('#field12').val() != ''){
        $('#result1').text(commafy(Math.round( $('#field11').val() + $('#field12').val() / $('#field13').val() * 1.5)) + ",99");
         }
     });
     if($('#field11').val() == '' || $('#field12').val() == '' || $('#field13').val() == ''){
         $('#result1').text('')
     }
});
```

Here is the working code on JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/x7a91bnx/

Thank you!

Comment: It is not possible to cast all your fields in Integer (parseInt) if its NaN just give him 0 ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can improve your logic by using DRY principles. As all the `keyup` handlers are performing the same logic you can extract that to its own function. Then in that function, you can retrieve each field's value, setting it to `0` if it's empty. You can also check that `#field13` has a value before doing the calculation to avoid division by zero problems. Also note that the `commafy()` function can be simplified too.

Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#field11, #field12, #field13').keyup(calculate);
});

function commafy(num) {
    return num.toString().replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ".");
}

function calculate() {
    var field11 = parseFloat($('#field11').val()) || 0;
    var field12 = parseFloat($('#field12').val()) || 0;
    var field13 = parseFloat($('#field13').val()) || 0;
    var result = field13 == 0 ? 0 : commafy(Math.round(field11 + field12 / field13 * 1.5)) + ",99";
    $('#result1').text(result);
}
```

[**Updated fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/x7a91bnx/6/)

Comment: My coding is rather clunky, I didn't even know you can assign a single event to three different fields. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Your intuition to check every input was right, but you must check it every time before the calculation happens, and not just one time after the document has been loaded. In example:

```
$('#field13').keyup(function () {
    if ($('#field11').val() !== '' || $('#field12').val() !== '' || $('#field13').val() !== '') {
        $('#result1').text(commafy(Math.round(parseFloat($('#field11').val()) + parseFloat($('#field12').val()) / parseFloat($('#field13').val()) * 1.5)) + ",99");
    } else {
        $('#result1').text('');
    }
});
```

Comment: Yes, I can see how that would make more sense... Thank you for your answer.